# c# factory of classes implementing the same interface

Tags: c#, factory-pattern

I'd like to create a factory that creates objects using text parameters.
The classes that need to be created do not derive from a single base class but implement the same interface.

```
public class Square: IPrintable
{
...
}

public class Triangle: IPrintable
{
...
}

interface IPrintable
{
   void print();
}
```

I would like to be able to create objects in the following way:

```
PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings("something");
ShapeFactory.Instance().Create("Triangle", settings);
```

I thought of creating a factory that contains a  map to handle the string IDs in the following way:

```
public class ShapeFactory
{
    static ShapeFactory singleton;
    Dictionary<string, XXX > map;

    private ShapeFactory(){};

    public static ShapeFactory Instance()
    {
       ...
       return singleton;
    }

    public void register(string ID, XXX obj);

    public IPrintable Create(string ID, PrinterSettings obj);
}

public SquareFactory
{...}

public TriangleFactory
{...}
```

I am struggling to find what class to use as values of my map to make it all work. Please let me know if there are some serious design issues above.

Comment: SquareFactory & TriangleFactory etc can all Implement IPrintableFactory and your register / map can use IPrintableFactory.  IPrintableFactory can have IPrintable Create(PrinterSettings obj) as it method.

Answer (score 0):

It considered a code smell to pass type information as a string in a strongly-typed language like C#. Often, you'd see this written as:

```
ShapeFactory.Instance().Create(typeof(Triangle), settings);
```

or simply

```
ShapeFactory.Instance().Create<Triangle>(settings);
```

What you are asking for could be accomplished, but it would be better to pass the type information along rather than looking up the type when it came time to instantiate the object. If you need to create a type from the class name, look at [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see how to do that. It can be non-trivial to resolve types, so you may also want to read up on Reflection as well, to see how type resolution is accomplished by the framework.

Comment: The string is a constraint of the problem. The Factory is called a lot. Isn't reflection slow?

Comment: Yes, which is why I don't recommend it, for the reasons mentioned above.